# nothing happens when creating dialog at quickblox android

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to connect to a group chat with quickblox. following the samples I made this snippet:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Logged into chat service successfully, creating dialog...");
if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
    Looper.prepare();
}
QBDialog dialogToCreate = new QBDialog();
dialogToCreate.setName("Test");
dialogToCreate.setType(QBDialogType.GROUP);
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a.add(qbUser.getId());
dialogToCreate.setOccupantsIds(a);
QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager().createDialog(dialogToCreate, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBDialog>() {
    @Override
     public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Dialog created");
        ConversationActivity.this.dialog = dialog;
        initViews();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess without data");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating dialog: "+ errors.toString());
    }
});
```

but the callback in `createDialog` is never triggered. No error is received. What may I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post logs from LogCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! I was creating session with wrong method. Now I'm using `QBAuth.createSession(QBUser, QBEntityCallbackImpl)` if user has already logged in, and `QBAuth.createSession(QBEntityCallbackImpl)` followed by `QBUsers.signUp()` if not.

Not sure where is this on docs/samples, though...